# TypeHint for collection in Enunciate

Tags: java, annotations, type-hinting, code-documentation, enunciate

I have some REST services (consuming and producing application/json) and I use `@TypeHint` to generate documentation.

Now I have something like this:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
...

@Path("/path")
public class MyClass {

    @GET
    @TypeHint(MyResponse.class)
    public Response getIt() {

        MyResponse resp = ... ;
        return MyBuilder.build(resp);
    }
}
```

but `MyResponse` is a wrapper over `List<MyType>`.

My `build` method from `MyResponse` looks like this:

```
public static Response build(Serializable payload) {
    return Response.ok(msr).header(...).build();
}
```

I want to use directly `List<MyType>` instead of `MyResponse`. Which is the best way to use `TypeHint` in the following code?

```java
    @GET
    @TypeHint(/* TODO */)
    public Response getIt() {

        List<MyType> myList = ... ;
        return MyBuilder.build(myList);
    }
```

I was thinking to the following options:

1. `@TypeHint(List.class)`
2. `@TypeHint(MyType.class)`
3. `@TypeHint(List<MyType>.class)` -> unfortunately this doesn't work because of Java type erasure.

**Question:**

Is there a valid **alternative for number 3**?

---

Even if the type is a `List`, number **1** is not useful because my own type has to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and that `List` is unchangeable (it is from JDK).

There is a **workaround** for number **2**, but it's not quite perfect:

- Use number 2 (just to have an available example in the generated HTML documentation - a description for an element that is contained in that list)
- Specify that it is a `List` in Javadoc (E.g.: after the `@return` word) (it can be emphasized using bold, colors, italics, etc. via HTML tags)

  E.g.:

  ```
  /**
   * ...
   * @return <strong><font color="blue">List&lt;MyType&gt;</font></strong>
   */
  ```

**Details:**

- enunciate.version = 1.30.1
- Java 7

Answer (score 5):

I have opted for using MyType[].class when using TypeHint instead of List.class. This way the documentation will state "array of MyType" which for my rest-api with json is true.

```
@TypeHint(value = MyType[].class)
```

Comment: This can be a better answer, but unfortunately now I can't test it to confirm if you are right or not.

Comment: Great idea :) Doesn't work in all parametrized type cases but helps me so far :)

Answer (score 1):

As you know **TypeHint** is used to give Enunciate a hint about what a JAX-RS **resource method returns** or **accepts as an input parameter**.

In your case **the return type** is being described.

I assume that the ClassReturnedByMyBuildersBuildMethod is a subclass of the javax.ws.rs.core.Response abstract class.
For the code as you showed it what you need to use is the class returned by MyBuilder's build method - **`@TypeHint(ClassReturnedByMyBuildersBuildMethod.class)`**.

Options 2 @TypeHint(MyType.class) makes no sense. It is not a return type nor an input parameter.

**Update 1: with your workaround it can make some sense :)**

If you add an input parameter to the getIt method - something like `public Response getIt(List<MyType> myList){...` you would use option 1(`@TypeHint(List.class)`) because as you know the **org.codehaus.enunciate.jaxrs.TypeHint** annotation type element declaration has a **Class** return type (`Class<?> value();`) and  you cannot use a parameterized type beacuse of the erasure of generic types (the paramterized type share the same class at runtime in this case - **List**).

But changing the input parameter to `getIt(List<MyType> myList)` **is probably not viable** because the list would have to be obtained from the URI ( with javax.ws.rs's @QueryParam or @Context UriInfo ). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input) addresses best practices when using list of parameters as input if it may concern you.

**Update 2: Option 1 becomes is less viable because of your XmlRootElement constraint.**

**Update 3: I see no valid alternative for option 3 using the TypeHint annotation as it is.**

You will have to go with your custom option 2 workaround.

Comment: 1) I agree with your first sentences.
2) Yes, my builder returns a `Response`
3) I've never tried to use that `Response` type for `TypeHint` because it worked perfectly (according to what I wanted to achieve) when I used the type that was "wrapped" into that response. 
4) I don't use that `List<MyType>` as a parameter for my function. It is wrapped into the returned result.
I need to have some attempts according to your suggestions before I can say if your answer is useful or not.

Comment: It didn't work. Value for `element` is seen as `(custom)` instead of a hyperlink that goes to a JSON sample. So, it is not better than my workaround described in the question.