# How to accept a list query parameter with standard format in DRF using django_filters

Tags: python, filter, django-rest-framework, query-string, multiple-choice

I want to be able to accept a list query param using the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176496/4650346. For example to filter products by a list of categories, I would like to use:

```
http://my.api.com/products?category[]=shirts&category[]=sweaters
```

I can create a FilterSet that acomplish this multiple choice filtering, the issue is that it won't follow the standard as I am unable to add the suffix `[]` that express it is a list. The following class demonstrates the functionality that I need.

```py
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(), 
        name='categories'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['category',]
```

That code, will allow users to create requests as:

```
http://my.api.com/products?category=shirt&category=sweaters
```

Question is: how can I add the suffix `[]` to the GET parameters that represent a list in the URI?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

This is a *kind-of dirty* fix I made to temporarily solve the problem. I extended the `DjangoFilterBackend` to override the `filter_queryset` method so whenever a field came in the form of `category[]`, I add the `category` field to the request.query_params.

```
from rest_framework.filters import DjangoFilterBackend

class DjangoFilterBackendListsFix(DjangoFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        filter_class = self.get_filter_class(view, queryset)

        query_params = request.query_params.copy()
        for qp in request.query_params:
            if qp[-2:] == '[]':
                query_params.setlist(qp.rstrip('[]'), query_params.getlist(qp))

        if filter_class:
            return filter_class(query_params, queryset=queryset).qs

        return queryset
```

So now in settings.py I've got `DjangoFilterBackendListsFix` as my default filter backend.

I'm still hoping to get an *elegant-er* solution, but in the meantime my client can happily consume the Restful API.