# Can a rest request input a multidimensional array or map?

Tags: c#, arrays, rest, dictionary, filter

I want to turn a request like

`foo.com/missions?type=flight&location=USA`

into a multidimensional array or a map so that I can use them later in a filter.

The names of the parameters and the number of parameters are all variable.

This is in C# using WEB API.

To clarify:

```
[Route("missions")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage SearchMissions(Dictionary<string, string> filters) // Dictionary may not be the most appropriate; I'm new to C#
{
    ...
}
```

The keys are type and location and the values are flight and USA.

Comment: you can via POST but i doubt when using GET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API Best practice: How to accept list of parameter values as input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input)

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu I have reviewed that other question and, while good information, does not answer my question. I need a collection that contains not just the value of the input parameters, but the names of the input parameters as well. The name of the collection that would be referenced in the code would be more like "params" and not type or location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are describing, you can get the request's query and parse it into key value pairs that you can use to extract the information you need.

```
[Route("missions")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage SearchMissions() {

    //Get the parsed query string as a collection of key-value pairs.
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> filters = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

    //...
}
```