# List of parameters in flask: reading only first value getlist()

Tags: python, url, curl, flask, parameter-passing

I would like to pass a list as parameter to flask via [getlist()](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist).
Reading here:
[REST API Best practice: How to accept list of parameter values as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input)

Could you help figuring out why this simple code failed to read a list parameter (skip_id) ?

```
def api_insight(path):
    import pdb
    skip_id = request.args.getlist('skip_id', type=None)
    print( 'skip_id', skip_id)
    pdb.set_trace()

curl http://myexample.com/<mypath>/?&skip_id=ENSG00000100030,ENSG00000112062  
# empty list


curl http://myexample.com/<mypath>/?&skip_id=[ENSG00000100030,ENSG00000112062]
# empty list

curl http://myexample.com/<mypath>/?&skip_id=ENSG00000100030&skip_id=ENSG00000
# only first value is read in list
```

Answer (score 4):

The last way should actually work. I just tried it in my Browser.

```
http://localhost:5000/api?skip_id=ENSG000001000301&skip_id=ENSG00000
```

Gives me

```
['ENSG00000100030', 'ENSG00000']
```

However with curl you will get into trouble with the `&` character as it will put the task in the background (at least if you're on Linux). With curl you can use

```
curl -X GET -G http://localhost:5000/api?skip_id -d skip_id=ENSG00000100030 -d skip_id=ENSG00000
```

to get your described result.