# update variables with REST Call in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: rest, api, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Is it possible to update several variables with REST Call in Alfresco Activiti with the request mapping , 
runtime/process-instances/${processInstanceId}/variables

I succefully updated one single variable with PUT method
runtime/process-instances/${processInstanceId}/variables/${variable_name}
 but cant map a json request in the request mapping to update more than one variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use request body if you want to pass multiple variables rather using in the browser url. 
If you use the url, the end user will be knowing the entire values of your request. You can refer start-workflow request, task-edit page requests to the Repo calls.

There is a nice discussion [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input)

Please share your thoughts / concerns as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I indicated eariler in this Activiti Forum post:
https://community.alfresco.com/thread/229928-rest-call-put-method-with-request-mapping

Putting the variables in an array works as seen in the following screenshot of a successful PUT request to a process instance:

[image]