# Read String Array in Django API

Tags: python, django, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have EmberJS front-end which calls Django REST API. I am passing string array from front-end to the API as shown below:

*Back-end Request*
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/User/search/?active=true&city%5B%5D=newyork&city%5B%5D=chicago&city%5B%5D=boston

*HTML Decoded*
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/User/search/?active=true&city[]=newyork&city[]=chicago&city[]=boston

Some how I am not able to get rid of the extra **%5B%5D** (which is square brackets) from this request as EmberJS automatically adds that as the parameter is passed as string array. I searched over several forums but did not get a solution for it.

How to read the string array (City parameter) in Django API and get all passed values from EmberJS front-end?

Comment: `request.GET.getlist('city[]')`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to get rid of the `[]`. The are [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602043) to indicate "I really do want to pass an array, i.e. multiple values for this query parameter".

The `[]` are presumably there because ember-data in your front end uses `coalesceFindRequests`. Dustin Farras (the main author of the ember-Django-adapter) has written [an article about using his adapter with `coalesceFindRequests`](http://dustinfarris.com/ember-django-adapter/coalesce-find-requests/#coalescefilterbackend): You can define a filter that covers `[]` and simply tell the django-rest-framework to use it:

> ```
> # myapp/filters.py
> from rest_framework import filters
>
> class CoalesceFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
> """
> Support Ember Data coalesceFindRequests.
> """
> def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
>     id_list = request.query_params.getlist('ids[]')
>     if id_list:
>         # Disable pagination, so all records can load.
>         view.pagination_class = None
>         queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=id_list) # adapt here, see note below
>     return queryset
> ```
>
> Now you just need to add this filter to filter_backends in your views, e.g.:
>
> ```
> from myapp.filters import CoalesceFilterBackend
>
> class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
>     queryset = User.objects.all()
>     serializer = UserSerializer
>     filter_backends = (CoalesceFilterBackend,)
> ```
>
> Or, configure it globally in your DRF settings:
>
> ```
> REST_FRAMEWORK = {
> 'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('myapp.filters.CoalesceFilterBackend',) }
> ```

Note: You will need to adapt the filter for `cities`, of course. (When filtering for primary keys, I prefer to `filter` for `pk__in=` instead of `id__in=` that also covers primary keys with names other than `id`.)