# How can I make GET request with an array

Tags: angular, httpclient

```
let owners = ['Chris', 'John'];

this.http.get('/pets', {'owners': owners}).subscribe(...);
```

The request goes like `.../pets/owners=Chris&owners=John`

But I want to request like `.../pets/owners=['Chris', 'John']`.

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: `JSON.Stringify(owners)`?

Comment: possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input

Comment: This shouldn't be done like that. You should start from refactoring your API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just curious as to why is your API is expecting you to send the request something like this?

This data that you're sending should be either sent as a request payload to a POST request. Something like this:

```
let owners = ['Chris', 'John'];
this.http.post(`/pets/owners`, { owners }).subscribe(...);
```

Or you should send it as a GET request but then as query params in that case:

```
let owners = ['Chris', 'John'];
this.http.get(`/pets?owners=${owners.toString()}`).subscribe(...);
```

If you still are sending the data like this, how exactly is your server intercepting this request? Why I'm asking that is because you are not setting the `owners` array as a value to anything.

If you still want to sent it like this, here's how you'd do that:

```
let owners = ['Chris', 'John'];
this.http.get(`/pets/owners=${JSON.stringify(owners)}`).subscribe(...);
```

But then again, I'm not really sure how your backend is making sense of this request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather using a post request and passing the list of owners in the request body.

e.g.:

```
public serviceMethod(owners): Observable<expectedType> {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  let params = new HttpParams();
  return this.http.post('/pets', owners, {headers: headers, params: params});
}
```

You can then subscribe to the service method where you need to use it:

```
service.serviceMethod(['Chris', 'John']).subscribe(...);
```