# Spring Boot does not accept list params enclosed in brackets

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have the following extremely simple SpringBoot program

```
// APIEndpoints.java

// Imports!

public class APIEndpoints {
    @PostMapping("deduplicate")
    public String deduplicate(@RequestParam(value = "data") String data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

```
// RestServiceApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I can start the springboot server via `./gradlew bootRun`, and have verified that the server is working through other endpoints.

Here is my issue: using postman to send a post request, the following goes off without a hitch

```
localhost:8080/deduplicate?data=1,23,4,5
```

However, this one fails with an error: "HTTP 400: Bad Request"

```
localhost:8080/deduplicate?data=[1,23,4,5]
```

This seems like undesirable behavior, and it [doesn't seem to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input) a fundamental limitation of url formatting or anything like that.

What is causing this error, and how can I set up Spring Boot to accept lists enclosed in brackets?

Comment: is postman encoding the brackets?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but the text displayed in my post is exactly what I enter into Postman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the main reason for getting this error is the characters "[" and "]". More details about  URLs and URIs allowed characters in this answer: [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/13500078#13500078).

The best way (following the standard)  - encode URL on client side:

```
encodeURL("localhost:8080/deduplicate?data=[1,23,4,5]")
>localhost:8080/deduplicate?data=%5B1%2C23%2C4%2C5%5D
```

Using postman, you want to select your data in query params window, click right mouse button and select "EncodeURIComponent":

[Example of encoding using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PKDu.png)
 will transfer your URL to

```
 localhost:8080/deduplicate?data=%5B1%2C23%2C4%2C5%5D
```

And it can be successfully read by tomcat (i suppose you use it as servlet container).

If you can not change your front-end behavior, you can use

> relaxedQueryChars / relaxedPathChars

in the connectors definition to allow these chars.
  Using java and spring (if tomcat is embedded):

```
    @Component
    public class TomcatWebServerSettings implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
        @Override
        public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector ->
            {
                connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "[]");
            });
        }
    }
```

Or you can add `relaxedQueryChars` attribute under server.xml (%TOMCAT_FOLDER%/conf/):

```
  <Connector 
        //other params,
          relaxedQueryChars="[,]"
         />
```

Also, you can downgrade your tomcat to version under 7.0.76 (strongly not recommended - security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

either

> deduplicate?data=1,23,4,5

or

> deduplicate?data=1&data=23&data=4&data=5

thats how it work if you want to as an array via REST API as request param.

Answer (score 0):

You are using unsafe characters in url, therefore you have troubles. [RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

```
" < > # % { } | \ ^ ~ [ ] ` including the blank/empty space.
```