# load multi-dimensional GET query string into []string

Tags: go

```
?select[0]=id,client_id,timout&select[1]=more,fields&data=test
```

How to load this query string into a []string?

```
[]string{
    "id,client_id,timout",
    "more,fields",
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/7_ZPyx0-TnF - given this you can turn it into what you exactly want with one extra loop

Comment: @zerkms it's not really doing what I want. It creates `select[0]` and `select[1]`.. I want ONE slice of `select`

Comment: It does not indeed, have you read my entire comment?

Answer (score 1):

[The standard way to pass a list of values as URL parameters is to repeat them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602127/1726083).  If you use the following syntax:

```
?select=id,client_id,timout&select=more,fields&data=test
```

[`URL.Query()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.Query) will return [a `Values map[string][]string` that will already contain under `select`](https://go.dev/play/p/_r1CMFbHIvU):

```
[]string{"id,client_id,timout", "more,fields"}
```

Comment: But the "standard" way is not always what is used.. `select[]` is more common.. eg. `select[name]`

Comment: If you name the fields different things they won't be collected under the same key of `URL.Query()`.  So you'll have to combine them yourself with, eg ,a regexp.

Comment: @clarkk, what leads you to believe that’s more common? Technically `[` and `]` aren’t even allowed unencoded in a query string.

Comment: @JimB allowed or not.. It's still used

Comment: Let me rephrase "select[] is more common": "The select[] abomination is common in the PHP world."